# MySQL stored procedure debugging

Tags: mysql, debugging, stored-procedures

do you have any tips for some GUI applications (free) that are capable of debugging MySQL stored procedures?

I tried devArt dbForge MySQL Studio which worked just fine, but it's not free.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Definitely take a look at SQLyog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there don't appear to be any free alternatives.

There is [Illatis Stepin](http://www.illatis.com/product/product.php) - an Eclipse-based IDE for debugging stored procedures. Price is $40 per licence. There is also [MySQL Debugger](http://www.mydebugger.com/), $50 per head. However, MyDebugger are [offering licences](http://www.mydebugger.com/special_offer.php) if you have a blog - you get a license in return for blogging about the product.

Is the debugger for use in an open source project? If so you might try contacting the publishers to see if they will grant you a license, perhaps in return for a mention on your project page.

If it's for commercial development, you might try getting approval for the $40-50 license fee. The debugger could potentially save you hours of time, and so will almost certainly pay for itself within the first year, if not quicker.

If neither of those are options, you might setup a small blog and try to get a free MyDebugger licence!

Answer (score 2):

MySql Connector/NET starting v6.6 has support for debugging stored routines using visual studio debugger look & feel, it's also open source (dual license GPL/MySql).

To download it here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.6.html

For documentation check here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-visual-studio-debugger.html

Comment: No, does not work with Express edition (legal Microsoft constraints).

Answer (score 1):

SQLYog Community Edition might be able to do this sort of thing 
http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying phpmyadmin.

Recent versions have a ["delimiter" field separate from the SQL window](http://blog.nth-design.com/2009/02/25/creating-sp-in-phpmyadmin/) that can be used to assist in generating stored procedures.

I am not certain that phpmyadmin has features specifically designed to help you sort out what is wrong with your stored procedure, but it does have a helpful "two window" mode for debugging sql generally (look for the "show this query in a new window" and then once youhave the new window be sure to click "do not overwrite this sql" checkbox. That will let you edit the query in one window and see the results in another.

HTH,

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but brought more beer:

http://ocelot.ca/blog/blog/2015/03/02/the-ocelotgui-debugger/
and
https://github.com/ocelot-inc/ocelotgui

I tried, and it seems pretty stable, supporting Breakpoints and Variable inspection.

It's not a complete suite (just 4,1 Mb) but helped me a lot!

How it works:
It integrates with your mysql client (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04), and after you execute:

```
$install
$setup yourFunctionName
```

It installs a new database at your server, that control the debugging process. So:

```
$debug yourFunctionName('yourParameter')
```

will give you a chance to step by step walk your code, and "refreshing" your variables you can better view what is going on inside your code.

*Important Tip: while debugging, maybe you will change (re-create the procedure). After a re-creation, execute: $exit and $setup before a new $debug*

This is an alternative to "insert" and "log" methods.
Your code remains free of additional "debug" instructions.

Screenshot:

[image: ocelot breakpoint stepping]

Comment: This is EXCELLENT!  I'm running windows with mysql server hosted locally (for .net web development), and have a linux vm (and of course wsl, but not full gui in there and all the headaches that go along with wsl, so I tend to use my ubuntu vm more than wsl for "real" linux apps/dev, where as I used wsl for using bash tools on windows files).  

After installing ocelot gui using the wget from their home page (not github), I connected, debugged their tutorial, and am amazed.  it's a GREAT step debugger with variable data view on demand.  lots to learn, but the #1 choice so far for free.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely take a look at [mySQL Debugging tool](http://mysql-tools.com/en/mysql/54-other-links/56-review-debug-mysql.html)

Comment: link is broken now