# MySQL Stored Procedure Debugging Strategy When Involving Transaction

Tags: mysql, debugging, stored-procedures

I was handed down a complex MySQL stored procedures that has TRANSACTION and tasked to find out an issue. I've followed [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273437/how-do-you-debug-mysql-stored-procedures) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007625/mysql-stored-procedure-debugging) here in stackoverflow on "debugging a stored procedure" and produces my own process:

**Log table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `dt_sp_process_logs` (
`serial` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`params` TEXT,
`message` TEXT NOT NULL,
`createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**SP for logging:**

```
DELIMITER %% CREATE PROCEDURE `spWriteLog`(
  IN `serialCode` VARCHAR(20),
  IN `params` TEXT,
  IN `messageText` TEXT
)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dt_sp_process_logs(`serial`, `params`, `message`)
    VALUES(serialCode, params, messageText);

END %%
```

I've called the SP inside my to-be-debugged SP:

```
BEGIN
  SET code = 0;

  SET serialN = CONCAT(
    'OR',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ':', ''), '-', ''), ' ', ''),
      (CAST(RAND() * 60 AS UNSIGNED) + 1)
  );

  START TRANSACTION

  -- -------
  -- long and
  -- complex process
  -- that determine
  -- code value
  -- -------

  CALL spWriteLog(serialN, "", CONCAT("subTotalItems: ", subTotalItems, " || subTotal: ", subTotal));

  -- -------
  -- long and
  -- complex process
  -- that determine
  -- code value
  -- -------

  IF code = 1 THEN
    COMMIT;
  ELSE
    ROLLBACK;
  END IF;

END
```

But it doesn't gets recorded in my `dt_sp_process_logs`. My immediate conclusion is that because this SP is called inside transaction, it doesn't gets saved when the to-be-debugged procedure called for "rollback". Is there any other technique I can learn?

Comment: I see not transaction or rolllback.

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry, I included the transaction and rollback process

Comment: You need to expose a bit more of your code as is you get an unknown column error on serialN

Comment: updated with serialN initialization.

Comment: If you rollback your transaction, that includes changes you made to the log tables  inside that transaction (as that is what a transaction is supposed to do). A workaround is to use MyISAM tables for logging, which do not support transactions, and thus won't get rolled back.

Comment: thank you @Solarflare, please move your comment as an answer and I'll vote as accepted!

Comment: hm usually you set up a couple of user defined variables and enter there the viltal debugging information, and after running the stored procedure you select them and see if you can grasp the problem, or do you need more information